Time domain expression of a stationary continous broadband signal and its autocorrelation
I want to find the auto-correlation of a stationary continous broadband signal.
The auto-correaltion is
$$f\star f=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^*(t)f(t+\tau)\ \mathrm{d}t.\tag{*}\label{*}$$
The power spectrum of the signal is
$$S(\nu)=\begin{cases}
S_0 & \mathrm{for\quad}\nu_0-\frac{\Delta \nu}{2}\leq\nu\leq\nu_0+\frac{\Delta \nu}{2}\\
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Note the the signal is statationary; It's average intensity doesn't change with time. The figure below emphasizes the difference between a stationary and nonstationary wave:

Figure from Saleh and Teich Fundamentals of Photonics.
I am familiar with the  Wiener-Khinchin theorem that relates the autocorrelation and the Fourier transform. For pedagogical reasons I want to mess with the algebra and see that evaluating the integral in \eqref{*} gives the same result as the Wiener-Khinchin theorem.

Is computing the Fourier Transfrom of the power spectrum $S(\nu)$ should return the time-dependence form of the signal?

$$f(t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{ S(\nu)\right\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S(\nu)\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\nu t}\ \mathrm{d}\nu=S_0 \Delta\nu\mathrm{sinc}\left(\Delta\nu t\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi \nu_0 t}$$
This signal decays to 0 amplitude for as $t\to \infty$. In other words, it is not stationary.
I think that the answer is no, because that infromation about the phase is not present in the expression for $S(\nu)$.

What is an expression for $f(t)$ such that $f\star f=\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|F(\nu)\right|^2\right\}$?


Not sure I understand the question.   The theorem states that the autocorrelation in time  and the magnitude square in frequency form a Fourier Transform pair. Are you looking for a proof of this?

I actually want to see an exact expression for a function $f(t)$ that gives the above mentioed $S(\vu)$.

It's really hard to decipher what exactly you are getting at, but I will say that a stationary signal is much more strict than the average intensity not varying with time, that is simply a consequence of it being stationary. Additionally, you ask "Is computing the Fourier Transfrom of the power spectrum $S(\nu)$ should return the time-dependence form of the signal?". No, the inverse Fourier transform of the power spectrum is the autocorrelation sequence, which decays to 0 as $t\rightarrow\infty$, even for stationary signals.

@user74037: any $f(t)$ that is conjugate symmetric, i.e. $f(t) = f'(-t)$ will have the property that $f(t)*f(t) \rightarrow |F(\omega)|^2$

"This signal decays to 0 amplitude for as $t\to \infty$. In other words, it is not stationary."
Not so. It is the autocorrelation function of the signal that is decaying to $0$ as $t\to \infty$, not the signal itself.
